# ¿Como puedo abrir el CMD sin el proceso "explorer.exe", o desde el menu Ctrl+Alt+Supr?

Tags: windows, cmd

Muy buenos días a todos.

Últimamente estoy intentando conseguir abrir el CMD desde un menú de teclas rápido, o intentando añadirlo al menu de Ctrl+Alt+Supr, Pero todavia no he conseguido nada.
Mi objetivo es abrir el CMD con un atajo de teclas, y que funcione aun con el proceso `explorer.exe` eliminado.

Muchas gracias, y buenos días.

Comment: Abriendo el administrador de tareas y ejecutándolo desde ahi?

Comment: Si, eso es lo que he estado haciendo hasta ahora, pero yo busco algo mas directo. Muchas gracias igualmente :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues, presionando `shift + click derecho` te sale la opción `abrir ventana de comando`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes abrirlo con las teclas "Windows + R" después escribiendo `cmd` y enter.

Comment: Gracias, pero ya lo he intentado :(, no funciona. Yo lo estoy intentando sin el proceso `explorer.exe`